# julia - merging multiple streams in sorted order using iterators

Tags: algorithm, julia

How do i merge these arrays using iterators in sorted order?  The arrays are sorted but values may appear more than once.
Using iterators since the arrays may be bigger than memory.
The function should allow for any number of iterators to be combined.

```
a = [1, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
b = [2, 6, 7]

mergesort(a, b, ...)
```

Comment: does this help? https://discourse.julialang.org/t/looking-for-merge-algorithm/47473/2 . It doesn't use iterators, but I can't imagine it being too difficult to implement that functionality

Comment: If the same value appears in multiple iterators, how many times should it appear in the output?  That is, if you merge `[1, 1, 4, 5]` with `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would you expect `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]`?

Comment: If the latter, I would store pairs of `(value, iterator)` (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Core.Pair) in a heap (see https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/heaps/) using a `Base.Ordering` that orders on the value. Take out the pair, yield the value, get the next value (if any) from the iterator, make a new pair, put it back in the heap.

Comment: I don't see how you can sort something without keeping the sorted output in memory, or at least on file. How does that work if the inputs are too big for that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one with `Iterators.Stateful`:

```
a = [1, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
b = [2, 6, 7]
c = [2, 3, 4, 6]

iters = [Iterators.Stateful(arr) for arr in [a, b, c]]


while !isempty(iters)
    firsts = peek.(iters)
    _, idx = findmin(firsts)
    print(popfirst!(iters[idx]), ", ")
    isempty(iters[idx]) && deleteat!(iters, idx)
end
```

which prints `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9,`

Comment: Can this be done in such a way as to yield another stream?

Comment: Yes, you could write the same results to an io stream with print(io, popfirst!(iters[idx]), ", ")

Comment: This will be `O(m*n)` where `m` is the number of iterators and `n` is the number of elements.  My heap proposal is `O(n * log(m))`.  But for small `m`, your approach is probably faster. Separately, I'd suggest https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/#Base.Channel as a more flexible solution than an io stream.

Comment: @btilly where is your heap impl?

Comment: @BAR See my comment above about juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/heaps using `BaseOrdering` for  a heap,